# Decode string with \x in PHP that has char encoded over 255

Tags: php, utf-8, decode, encode

## My problem is about string decoding.

Let's assume a string like:

```php
$str = "\xce\xbb\xc6\x9b\xc2\xac\xe2\x88\xa7\xe2\x9f\x91\xe2\x88\xa8\xe2\x9f\x87\xc3\xb7 \xe2\x82\xac\xc2\xbd\xe2\x88\x86\xc3\xb8\xe2\x86\x94\xc2\xa2\xe2\x8c\x90\xc3\xa6";
```

I want to decode it and to look like that:
`λƛ¬∧⟑∨⟇÷ €½∆ø↔¢⌐æ`
I tried to use

```php
utf8_encode(utf8_encode($str));
```

But it's not what was expected.

In python something like that works:

```py
_str = b"\xce\xbb\xc6\x9b\xc2\xac\xe2\x88\xa7\xe2\x9f\x91\xe2\x88\xa8\xe2\x9f\x87\xc3\xb7 \xe2\x82\xac\xc2\xbd\xe2\x88\x86\xc3\xb8\xe2\x86\x94\xc2\xa2\xe2\x8c\x90\xc3\xa6"
_str = _str.decode()
print(_str)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to decode that. This is legal notation for [strings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) in PHP.

```
$str = "\xce\xbb\xc6\x9b\xc2\xac\xe2\x88\xa7\xe2\x9f\x91\xe2\x88\xa8\xe2\x9f\x87\xc3\xb7 \xe2\x82\xac\xc2\xbd\xe2\x88\x86\xc3\xb8\xe2\x86\x94\xc2\xa2\xe2\x8c\x90\xc3\xa6";
echo $str;  //λƛ¬∧⟑∨⟇÷ €½∆ø↔¢⌐æ
```

https://3v4l.org/0e0Po

Comment: Note: The strings must be in double quotes, not single quotes!